# Работа с очередью. Ошибка "CL.exe" завершилась с кодом 2

Tags: c++, указатели, очередь, локальные-переменные

Задание: Создать очередь, содержащую числа. В новой очереди вывести сначала отрицательные, затем положительные. Порядок ввода чисел сохранить.

Программа даже не запускается. В чем ошибка?

Мой код:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

//инициализация
struct queue {
    int inf;
    queue* next;
};    

void push(queue*& h, queue*&t, int x) { //вставка элемента в очередь
    queue * r = new queue; //создаем новый элемент
    r->inf = x;
        r-> next = NULL; //всегда последний
    if (!h && !t) 
    { //если очередь пуста
        h = t = r; //это и голова и хвост
    }
    else 
    {
        t-> next = r; //r - следующий для хвоста
        t = r; //теперь r - хвост
    }

}

int pop(queue*& h, queue*&t) { //удаление элемента из очереди
    queue * r = h; //создаем указатель на голову
    int i = h-> inf; //сохраняем значение головы
    h = h-> next; //сдвигаем указатель на следующий элемент
    if (!h) //если удаляем последний элемент из очереди
        t = NULL;
    delete r; //удаляем первый элемент
        return i;
}


int main() 
{
    int n; cout << " n = "; cin >> n; 
    struct queue* q; struct queue* tail = NULL;
    struct queue* neg; struct queue* tail_neg = NULL;
    struct queue* pos; struct queue* tail_pos = NULL; 
    struct queue* num; struct queue* tail_num = NULL;



    //создаем очередь (см 1) 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int x;
        cin >> x;
        push(q, tail, x);
    }

    // раскидываем числа + и - (см 2)
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int x;
        x = pop(q, tail);
        if (x >= 0)
        push(pos, tail_pos, x);
        else push(neg, tail_neg, x);
    }

    //в очередь num добавляем сначала neg, потом pos
    while (neg or pos)
    {
        while (neg)
        {
            int x;
            x = pop(neg, tail_neg);
            push(num, tail_num, x);
        }
    
        while (pos)
        {
            int x;
            x = pop(pos, tail_pos);
            push(num, tail_num, x);
        }
    }

    while (num)
        cout << pop(num, tail_num) << " ";
    cout << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас неинициализированные указатели -

```
struct queue* q; 
struct queue* neg;
struct queue* pos;
struct queue* num;
```

после чего вы начинаете их использовать - типа,

```
push(q, tail, x);
```

Но ведь в переменной `q` - просто какой-то мусор, а не указатель на корректную структуру `queue`. Как результат - неопределенное поведение, выражающееся у вас описанным образом (так как вы пытаетесь писать/читать в память, которая находится просто не пойми где...).